# Durandal Routing not working after calling reset method on router

Tags: routes, durandal, knockout-2.0, q

Before a user logs in, I configure the router object with routes to views everyone can see. One of those views is login.html. After the user provides username and password and is authenticated, I'm attempting to clear the router and load it with routes which are available to the logged-in user, based on the user's permissions.

My code for resetting the router is to call the reset() method on the router. If I DO NOT also call the deactivate() method on the router, I get an error message (from Q), with an unhandled rejection reason (saying the array should be empty) with the message, "History has already been activated...";

If I DO call the deactivate() method on the router (in addition to the reset() method, I get a message stating that the requested route is not found. If, instead of loading the router with generic routes that everyone can view, I load the routes which are being loaded after calling the reset and deactivate methods, I can navigate to the view I want, without any complaints from Q and I don't get the Route Not Found message, so the problem is NOT with the construction of the route.

My code for resetting the router follows these steps:

1. call reset() on the router.
2. call deactivate() on the router (or else I get the Q error described above).
3. call the map() method on the router, passing in my array of routes.
4. call the buildNavigationModel() method on the router. And finally,
5. return the router by calling the activate() method, and using hash property of my desired destination view as the parameter of the activate method.

It is at this point that I get the Route Not Found message, but as stated earlier, if I load this same set of routes into the router to begin with, I am able to navigate to this view using the same hash that is not found in the above scenario.

Can anyone see the problem and provide any suggestions on how to proceed? One last point is that I have a nav.html view which is a separate view loaded into my shell.html document and it correctly binds to the new set of routes, and that view loads and displays the new links based on the logged-in user's permissions, and if I click on the link which represents the 'Route Not Found' message, I am indeed taken to the desired view, which displays as expected.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Din you find a way to solve this ?thanks

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out. My solution involved responding to the click events of the nav controls (list item elements with embedded anchors) and calling router.navigate(data.hash) from the data element passed to the list item on click. I use a ko.observableArray to track which set of routes is active (there can be only one at a time). If that's not enough help, let me know and I'll send you some code in an email.